# Creating a Pie (highcharts) using a defined HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, highcharts

I would like to add series to a pie , i've created a JS function to do it :

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way to work with Highcharts and ASP.NET is to use [DotNet.Highcharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/) library. Here is the example with the Pie chart:

```
Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
            .InitChart(new Chart { PlotShadow = false })
            .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010" })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }" })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
                            {
                                Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
                                      {
                                          AllowPointSelect = true,
                                          Cursor = Cursors.Pointer,
                                          DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                                                       {
                                                           Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                                                           ConnectorColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000"),
                                                           Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %'; }"
                                                       }
                                      }
                            })
            .SetSeries(new Series
                       {
                           Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
                           Name = "Browser share",
                           Data = new Data(new object[]
                                           {
                                               new object[] { "Firefox", 45.0 },
                                               new object[] { "IE", 26.8 },
                                               new Point
                                               {
                                                   Name = "Chrome",
                                                   Y = 12.8,
                                                   Sliced = true,
                                                   Selected = true
                                               },
                                               new object[] { "Safari", 8.5 },
                                               new object[] { "Opera", 6.2 },
                                               new object[] { "Others", 0.7 }
                                           })
                       });
```

The result of this code is the same like at the highcharts demo: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-basic

In case to call JavaScript function when click on the chart you can do it simply like that:

```
Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
                {
                    Point = new PlotOptionsPiePoint
                            {
                                Events = new PlotOptionsPiePointEvents
                                         {
                                             Click = "OnPiePointClick"
                                         }
                            }
```

... or if it's simple function, you can add it directly:

```
Click = "function() { alert (this.category +': '+ this.y); }"
```

For the complete code or for more Pie examples download the sample project: http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/80650

Comment: Just a question : i put this on my code behind ( Page_Load fonctions for a test ) and a i added the Dll to my project. All is ok but nothing happens ... no graph appears ... is there anything else to do ?
thanks in advance

Comment: You can find a simple example at the home page of the project: http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/. Anyway, you need to have a Literal control on your page `<asp:Literal ID="ltrChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>` and then you can pass the HtmlString of the chart like this: `ltrChart.Text = chart.ToHtmlString();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a div in the html page with the id `container` to drop the chart into (because of this line in your chart config: `renderTo: 'container'`.  The Highcharts forums are very helpful for Highcharts support.

When debugging this, I would try taking the chart out of the asp page first and just generating it in striaghtforward html, it will be easier to see what is going wrong

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I simply forgot to post here the code concerning my container but it is present! the problem comes from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using ASP .Net, maybe you should try using [Highcharts.Net](http://www.highcharts.codeplex.com). The C# library lets you create Highcharts without writing any javascript code at all, all you write is C# code in the codebehind file. This is especially useful if you are puling data from a SQL datasource.

In fact, pulling data from a SQL source has been discussed [here](http://highcharts.codeplex.com/discussions/286773) and if you want a sample for using a Pie chart, you can always download the sample project containing examples from [here](http://highcharts.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets)

Comment: Thanks for your advice.
Actually my problem is to get the ID of an aera of the pie when i click on it ...
That's why i'm trying to pass a tag in my HTML table ...

Comment: If you use the Highcharts .Net API, you can use a point object instead of a simple numeric value to denote each slice in the Pie. For each point object, set the ID attribute which can then be retrieved on the javascript click event.